# ArrayLists with objects, sorting and finding the largest object (rectangle by area)

Tags: java, object, arraylist, max, area

I have a problem, I know how to sort an arrayList for integers and find the maximum, but I dont know how to do that when I have an arrayList of objects (rectangles) please can someone help with this algorithm.

Here is what ive done:

```
public static Rectangle largest(ArrayList < Rectangle > rectangles) {

 Rectangle max = rectangles.get(0);
 for (Rectangle temp: rectangles) {
  if (temp.getArea() > max.getArea())
   max = temp;

 }
 return max;
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with current approach?

Comment: this works fine; continue on with sorting

Answer (score 1):

If you're the one who has designed the program, you can make `Rectangle` implement `Comparable<Rectangle>`

```
public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
    // existing code
    public int compareTo (Rectangle r) {
        return Integer.compare(this.area, r.getArea());
    }
}
```

And then just use `Collections#sort`

```
Collections.sort(rectangles);
```

---

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)

If you're using this version of java, you may want to define your `Comparator` within the `sort` method using a `lambda` expression.

```
Collections.sort(rectangles, (rectangleOne, rectangleTwo) -> Integer.compare(rectangleOne, rectangleTwo));
```